# How to COUNT(*) WHEN COALESCE - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum, coalesce

I have this T-SQL statement that adds up all of `col1` and `col2` but also needs to return the number of rows returned by the `WHERE`

The only way I figured out how to do it is `count(FlightLogLegID - (FlightLogLegID - 1))` which results in summing 1 per row. I was hoping there would be a better way that doesn't require the needless addition and subtraction.

```
SELECT 
    coalesce((Select sum(Col1)),0) AS Number1,
    coalesce((Select sum(Col2)),0) AS Number2,
    coalesce((Select count(TableRowID - (TableRowID - 1)), 0) AS Number3
FROM 
    SomeTable 
WHERE ...
```

Example rows

```
TableRowID   Col1   Col2
1            5      10
2            3      5
3            12     8
```

Desired results

```
Number1   Number2   Number3
20        23        3
```

Comment: look at [Group by grouping sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: can you post sample records? `:D`

Comment: Are you asking about **MySQL** (like in your title) or **SQL Server** (as in your tags)?

Comment: I put MSSQL in my title, so SQL Server,
I will look into Group by grouping sets, thanks for the tip
Ill make an edit with sample records

Answer (score 1):

If it's as simple as your example suggests, with just one row being returned, all you need is this:

```
Select SUM(Col1)
     , SUM(Col2)
     , Count(*)
From   SomeTable
Where  <whatever>
```

`Coalesce` wouldn't be an issue:  Count(*) will count all records, even ones with nulls.

Comment: Coalesce would put 0 in place of null if a row has null for that number field. Wouldnt sum() fail in that circumstance?

Comment: @masteroleary no, SUM ignores NULLs. Did you try it? Or [read the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810(v=sql.100).aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were asking about?

```
SELECT SUM(Col1) [Number1], SUM(Col2) [Number2], COUNT(*) [Number3] 
FROM SomeTable
```

You can use this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/675e7/1) to check it out.